# Cохранение состояния в SPA при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: spa

В SPA (single page application) на определенной странице есть таблица с возможностью установки фильтров, пагинацией, сортировками колонок.

Скажите, практикуется ли в SPA подход, с сохранением установленных значений фильтров, сортировок, текущей страницы пагинации и результата в таблице, при перезагрузке страницы?

Т.е. установили фильтры, сортировку, пагинацию, получили результат в таблице, перезагрузили страницу (F5) - фильтры, сортировка, пагинация, результат в таблице остался на месте, до тех пор, пока не ушли на другую страницу.

Если практикуется такой подход, то какими средствами достигается этот результат?

Comment: Практикуется, если стоит такая задача. Сохранять можно в куки/localstorage и т.п.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.